# EF CodeFirst, one to many, EXACTLY IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Yes, I know EF doesn't support IEnumerable and need to use ICollection. But...

I have two class

```
public class Group
{
    public Guid ID;
    public String Title { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<Student> _students;
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get { return _students; } }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (_students.Any(x => x == student))
            throw new StudentException();

        _students.Add(student);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid ID;
    public String FirstName { get; private set; }
    public String LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

It is my domain layer. DB layer have reference to domain layer. The question is why I must change my domain layer for DB Layer? Of course, I don't must. Domain Layer doesn't know about DB Layer. Right?

**IMPORTANT! I don't want to change my Domain Layer for DB Layer.** So, how I can create tables via CodeFirst fluent api? (A group have many students and student has zero or one group.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can configure the DbContext to have a mapping without a navigation property. But then you'll have to populate your **Students** property manually.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Group)
    .WithMany();
```

If you want to have it populated automatically, you'll have to use ICollection (you can't have the cake and eat it too).

Maybe you should think about using interfaces to code against, so you wouldn't have to worry about private sets, readonly collections and so on. Something like:

```
public interface IGroup
{
    Guid ID { get; }
    String Title { get; }

    IEnumerable<IStudent> Students { get; }

    void AddStudent(IStudent student);
}
```

Just a suggestion though :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think configuration a mapping without a navigation property is good idea for me. But I don't know how to do it. Student type has not Group Property.

Comment: I didn't notice that... You just need some foreign key. It's either add a foreign key to the Group or make the Students ICollection.. sorry :(

Comment: I have thought about my model one more time. I added Group property to Student class. So thank you again